# Lightkurve error - Attribute Error: "NoneType" object has no attribute 'Sap_Flux'

Tags: python, pandas, astropy

I have an excel file with basic information on 50,001 Kepler objects. I am trying to read the column of Kepler ID's with pandas, then put those ID's into a Lightkurve search, where I can make a comnined lightcurve of all quarters of observational data. Here is my code:

```
import os
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table, Column
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
import pandas as pd 
from astroquery.mast import Observations
import lightkurve as lk
from lightkurve import search_lightcurvefile 
from astropy.io import fits 


data = pd.read_excel ('C:\keplerDataSet.xlsx') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Kepler_ID']) 
idlist = df[1:2]

for obj in idlist:
   lc = search_lightcurvefile('obj', quarter=1).download().SAP_FLUX.normalize()
   for q in range(2,17):
        lc = lc.append(search_lightcurvefile('obj',quarter=q).download().SAP_FLUX.normalize())
```

The error that it gives me is this: 
'Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Sap_Flux'

I am an undergrad and I am fairly new to programming, so any constructive criticism is very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object returned by the call to `download` doesn't have a SAP_FLUX attribute.

If you try the following, you will be able to see the string representation of the download (which usually includes the type name which is helpful in googling) and what attributes it has in a big python list.

```py
for obj in idlist:
   download = search_lightcurvefile('obj', quarter=1).download()
   print(download, dir(download))
   download.SAP_FLUX.normalize()
```

Comment: Thank you. That's really helpful. I think the issue is somewhere in the way that the objects are getting put into the lightkurve search. So I think something on the pandas side. It's looking like what's happening is instead of inputting the numbers in the columns (the column that I am trying to read is a column of integer numbers which act as unique identifiers) it's just not putting in anything at all. Is there a different way to do a loop for something like this other than what I have done?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you need to specify the mission, because this search also calls from K2 and TESS.

So instead of

```
download = search_lightcurvefile('obj', quarter = 1).download()
```

you need

```
download = search_lightcurvefile('obj', mission = ['Kepler'], quarter = 1).download()
```